# Delete all rows that do not have the value: Criteria 1 or Criteria 2 or Criteria 3 in Column D --> Using VBA Macro for excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macro's/VBA and cannot seem to figure out how to do this action for multiple criteria. I am trying to Delete all rows that do not have the value: Identify Fail or Identify Success in Column D. I write the following code and it works for one criteria "Identify Fail":

'*********************************************************************************'

```
Sub DeleteRows()
'Action 1 --> Delete all Rows without Identify Fail in column D'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Fail" Then Rows(i).Delete shift:=xlUp
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

'*********************************************************************************'

Once I try to add 'OR' with another criteria it does not work:

'*********************************************************************************'

```
Sub DeleteRows()
'Action 1 --> Delete all Rows without Identify Fail in column D'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Fail" Or "Identify Success" Then   
Rows(i).Deleteshift:=xlUp
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

'*********************************************************************************'

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I have been scouring this website and have not found an efficient code that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
 If Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Fail" Or "Identify Success" Then
```

to

```
If Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Fail" Or _ 
   Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Success" Then
```

you have to specify the conditions in full..

However the conditions condridict each other so it will always pass..  I think you mean to use

```
If Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Fail" And _ 
   Range("D" & i).Value <> "Identify Success" Then
```

---

In this example I added "Identity Fail" to D10

[image: Example screenprint]

Comment: Thanks Sam, I did try that, but again I am getting an error in the code.

Comment: I checked the syntax and added an example. I didn't get any errors. Did you add the End If?

Comment: OMG. Forgot the End If... Thank you!